# Paging data loaded in razor pages partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm loading a partial view with data per https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/325/partials-and-ajax-in-razor-pages

My partial view just builds a table which I'm trying to page through with code built per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Unfortunately the jquery load function reloads the partial view without consideration for the paging/sorting/filtering information:

```
// Load data for the partial.
$(function () {
    $("#list").load("/Admin/ProviderTypes/Index?handler=Providers");
});
```

The page model defines this handler method with parameters for the paging/filtering/sorting:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetProviders(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex)
{
    var providerTypes = from p in context.ProviderTypes select p;

    var pageSize = config.GetValue("PageSize", 10);

    // Do filtering/sorting/etc. - removed for brevity.

    var _providerTypes = await PaginatedList<ProviderType>.CreateAsync(providerTypes.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(x => x.Name), 1, pageSize);

    return await LoadProviderTypesPartial(_providerTypes);
}
```

Then the data is pushed into the PartialViewResult which gets returned:

```
private async Task<PartialViewResult> LoadProviderTypesPartial(PaginatedList<ProviderType> items = null)
{
    if (items is null)
    {
        // Get new data if none is provided.
        var providerTypes = from p in context.ProviderTypes select p;
        var pageSize = config.GetValue("PageSize", 10);
        items = await PaginatedList<ProviderType>
            .CreateAsync(providerTypes.AsNoTracking(), 1, pageSize);
    }

    // Update the page model property.
    ProviderTypes = items;

    var result = new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_DataProviderTypesPartial",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<PaginatedList<ProviderType>>(ViewData, items)
    };
    return result;
}
```

How can I make my handler function actually apply the paging/sorting filtering?

Also I see that there is different behavior when a form is posted to the handler function from the partial versus when posting from the actual page itself. For example, when I post an item ID to a handler function from the table row on the partial for deletion, that handler can't return the PartialViewResult because then all I see on the browser is a list of the items in the partial's model - so that handler function probably should refresh or do some client-side work to remove the item from the table instead of simply reloading the partial.

With that in mind, should the controls for the paging/filtering be on the page or on the partial?

Comment: What does your sort filter mean? For example, I have 20 pieces of data, one piece for 10 pages, divided into 2 pages, are they sorted according to the number of pages?

Comment: No no, sorting is when you click on the column header and it sorts the values alphabetically/numerically. So 20 items split across 2 pages of 10 sorted by Name means page 1 starts at A, page 2 ends at Z